# Write a query to count patrons by patron type(pat_type) sorted in ascending sequence

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Hi everybody I had such a hard time answering this question. I can't seem to select two attributes ( Student and Faculty) and list the count of them.

My code:

```
SELECT PAT_TYPE, COUNT(*)
FROM PATRON 
WHERE LOWER(PAT_TYPE) LIKE 'student%' 
OR LOWER(PAT_TYPE) LIKE 'faculty%'
GROUP BY PAT_TYPE;
```

The table:
[Create Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D73GK.png)

[Contents in Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZNHC.png)

The correct output should look like this:

```
  PAT_TYPE   |  COUNT(*)
1. Faculty       6
2. Student       44
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What is your current output and why is that not what you want?

Comment: my current output listed all the student and faculty without case sensitivities and all the counts next to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```
select pat_type,count(*) as cnt
from
(select case when lower(pat_type) like 'student%' then 'student',
       else 'faculty' end as pat_type
from patron)
group by pat_type;
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: I was able to change your code to fit it to the output.                             
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: if the distinct pat_type are 2(student and faculty) you don't need to change anything.

Comment: It just needed to be ordered by pat_type and Student and Faculty had to be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data I think the following query should work:

```
SELECT LOWER(PAT_TYPE) AS PAT_TYPE, COUNT(*)
FROM PATRON 
WHERE LOWER(PAT_TYPE) IN ('student', 'faculty')
GROUP BY LOWER(PAT_TYPE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!